# Elastic search - search words forming a single word without spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index called *products* with the default index setting. It has a name field which is ***text*** type, so names like below it stores,

1. Lipstick matte
2. Lip balm

Now, issue arises when user searches ***Lip stick*** and it fetches Lip Balm first and Lipstick matte later.
I'm expecting a search result with Lipstick first.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need right relevancy to get the aspired result first.

You could improve the query by adding boost to your query. I'm guessing you are doing a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) here to get the results. You could also try using the [match phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) with slop set to 2.

Here is a blog, which explains about improving [relevancy](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-improve-elasticsearch-search-relevance-with-boolean-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the search usecases, you would need to play around the analyzers to decide how you would index the data in elastic search. This [elastic search analyzer blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-text-analysis-part-1) can help you to get started on basics. More detailed info about analyzers can be checked [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html).

This is important to understand because any quick or direct solution will just solve for a single usecase temporarily, but won't work for long run.

I played around your inputs on my machine and if you want to get unblocked on this, use following query:

```
GET mstemp/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "field",
            "query": "Lipstick",
            "boost": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "field",
            "query": "Lip stick"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I am making a search with users input after removing whitespace from it, and boosted its result, so that it will come on top.

Output:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "mstemp",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "AXk3SB3tNamWTgl09SXK",
    "_score": 0.51623213,
    "_source": {
      "field": "Lipstick matte"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "mstemp",
    "_type": "test",
    "_id": "AXk3SkoXLqUWVnBbDm5a",
    "_score": 0.25811607,
    "_source": {
      "field": "Lip balm"
    }
  }
]
```

Partial searches can be done by adding `*` at start and/or end of your query e.g. `"query": "*Lipstick*"`